# How can I use a property in a model in Loopback 4 (strongloop) and hide it in the /explorer (Ej: Autogenerated ID)

Tags: node.js, strongloop, loopback, loopback4

I have this model done in loopback 4:

```
@property({
    type: 'string',
    id: true,
    default: () => uuid(),
  })

  id: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  name: string;
```

As you see, the id is generated by default. But in the loopback/explorer

[image: image explorer]

The id appears. I want to hide it, if is going to be auto generated, It could produce a confusion to the developers that want to use this API. Anybody knows how to put a property in a model, and hide it from the `/explorer` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just exclude the id from the request body schema

```
@requestBody({
      content: {
        'application/json': {
          schema: getModelSchemaRef(Model, {exclude: ['id']}),
        },
      },
    }
```

Hope this helps 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:-

```
@model({
  settings: {hidden: ['password']}
})
class User extends Entity {
  // ...
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true
  })
  password: string;
}
```

Comment: this does not work.. neither does 'hiddenProperties'